# How to update a value in an ArcSde table using ArcMap's VBA

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, vba, update

First of all, I want to update a table, not a feature class (no geographical information). 
I tried the following

```
Public Sub updateInSql(tableName As String, whereClause As String, field As String, value As String)

    ' get table
    Dim pTable As ITable: Set pTable = getTableFromSQL(tableName) ' this is my function that gets the table object (it works for sure)
    If (pTable Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    Dim pQueryFilter As IQueryFilter: Set pQueryFilter = New QueryFilter
    pQueryFilter.whereClause = whereClause
    If (whereClause = "") Then Set pQueryFilter = Nothing

    Dim pCursor As ICursor: Set pCursor = pTable.Update(pQueryFilter, False)
    Dim pRow As IRow: Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    Do Until pRow Is Nothing
        pRow.value(pRow.fields.FindField(field)) = value
        pRow.Store
        Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    Loop

End Sub
```

I get "Automation Error" at "Set pCursor = pTable.Update(pQueryFilter, False)"
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

Just change

```
pTable.Update(pQueryFilter, False)
```

to

```
pTable.Search(pQueryFilter, False)
```

and it works